# how to catch increment and decrement events for dijit.form.NumberSpinner?

Tags: events, dojo, dijit.form

Is there any way to catch increment and decrement events for dijit.form.NumberSpinner when user presses up or down arrow in this widget? I know "_arrowPressed" event but I don't want to use it for some reasons. I am using onChange event but that doesn't get fired until you lose focus on this widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `intermediateChanges:true` to get `onChange` on every change (w/o losing focus):

```
<div
    id="spinner1"       
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner"   
    data-dojo-props="
        name: 'spinner1',
        smallDelta: 1,
        largeDelta: 10,
        constrains: {min: 0, max: 100, places: 0},
        value: 10,
        intermediateChanges: true
    "    
></div>
```

See how it works at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/HCx3w/